# Azure cosmos db alias column order by

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have written a select query in cosmos db which works fine. But in that query when i try to add order by column on a alias column it does not work. Here distance is an alias column What is the correct way to do it ?

```
SELECT c.id,c.type,c.name,c.latitude,c.longitude,c.location, ST_Distance(c.location, { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[-112.215641, 33.181647]}) as distance FROM c WHERE ST_Distance(c.location, { 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates':[-112.215641, 33.181647]}) < 321868.8 ORDER BY c.distance ASC
```

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes.. i saw there is no support..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually,we are told that we can only sort with properties of document, not derived values. Please see this [link](https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/11/06/a-few-cosmosdb-query-limitations/).You `distance` column is derived value,can't be used at `order by`.

> “Unsupported ORDER BY clause. ORDER BY item expression could not be
>   mapped to a document path”

I would suggest you sort the query result by yourself.For example,in .net code,you could use [Sort](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/easily-sort-values-with-the-net-array-classs-sort-method/) function to sort the result by the column.